# React check radio button

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux

I have radio button inputs with an `onChange` callback that triggers a long action - a computation on the server. I want my input to update now to appear checked as soon as it is clicked, not only when the computation is finished - otherwise the user thinks he has not clicked right and keeps clicking.

So I cannot set the "checked" attribute with props, otherwise it has to wait for the end of the computation. Calling `myinput.checked = "checked"` in the `inChange` callback does not update it either.

My workaround is to write 10 ugly and stupid lines of code like theses ones so that a state updates first, and then we get the props at the end of the action:

```js
getInitialState: function () {
    // "anti-pattern", according to the docs
    return {value: this.props.value};
},

componentWillReceiveProps: function(nextProps) {   
    // because we use the state in the <input>, it needs to mirror the props
    // when they change for another reason. I call it dirty.
    this.setState({value: nextProps.value});
},

onChange: function (e) {
    this.setState({value: e.target.value});   // to update it right now
    Actions.longAction(e.target.value);   // long action
},

render: function() {
    ...
    return <input 
        ...
        type="radio"
        checked={ this.state.value === 1} 
    />;
}
```

Is there any better way to check right away, visually, the option that the user clicked ?

Comment: To pass a prop as an initial value to state is fine. It may be an anti-pattern, but is acceptable practice in react to use it to set initial value of state, as in your case, as explained [here in docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/props-in-getInitialState-as-anti-pattern.html)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I think I'll stick with it, then. Better that than passing callbacks around.

Answer (score 0):

In React, don't read DOM.
Instead, manage `checked` in you `Checkbox` component. Since checkbox only holds boolean value (checked), it's super easy. On every change, you invert this value and call `onChange` handler.

See this structure, feel free to edit it to your needs.

```
var Parent = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      checked: false,
    }
  },

  onChange(checked) {
    this.setState({ checked });
  },

  render: function() {
    return <Checkbox checked={this.state.checked} onChange={this.onChange} />;
  }
});

var Checkbox = React.createClass({
  onChange() {
    this.props.onChange(!this.props.checked);
  },

  render() {
    const props = {
      ...this.props,
      onChange: this.onChange,
    };

    return <input type="checkbox" {...props} />;
  }
});
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/37640/

Comment: Thanks, the fiddle indeed works fine if I add a setTimeout in the callback. I'll go for that and see. I am not sure which version is uglier, though.

Comment: Nice solution. The opening "In React, don't read DOM", is way too strong. In this particular case, you do not need to read the DOM, and in general: if avoidable, do not read from DOM. But there are many other cases where it is perfectly fine to read from DOM, e.g. to get a components height in DOM.

Comment: Actually this solution works for checkboxes because it updates when you click on it, but radio buttons must update when you click on *another one*. Moreover, since my props define the initial state, I have to do the same ugly stuff here as I did in my solution (componentWillReceiveProps etc.). In the end, I am not sure this is an improvement.

Comment: @wintvelt yep, it might be a bit strong. Generally, working with data, do not read it from DOM - you already have it somewhere (and can work with them). Your example is to the point.